# How to pass a specific xml filter in Powershell to request events?

Tags: xml, windows, powershell

```
# Define the remote server name
$remoteServer = "SERVER_NAME"

# Define the credentials for authentication
$username = "USERNAME"
$password = "PASSWORD"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList   $username, $securePassword

# Define the time range for the last half hour
$startTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
$endTime = Get-Date

# Define the event ID for Netlogon 5810
$eventID = 5810

# Construct the filter for the desired event ID and time range
$filter = @"
<QueryList>
    <Query>
        <Select Path="Security">
            *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=$eventID)]]
            and
            *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='$($startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))' and @SystemTime<='$($endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))']]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

# Retrieve the events from the remote server with authentication
$events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $remoteServer -FilterXml $filter -Credential $credential

# Count the number of events
$eventCount = $events.Count

# Display the result
Write-Host "Number of Netlogon 5810 events in the last half hour: $eventCount"
```

`

Running this code with powershell provides this error :

> Get-WinEvent : Impossible de lier le paramètre « FilterXml ».
> Impossible de convertir la valeur «     
>
>
> *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=5810)]]
> and
> *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='2023-06-14T13:24:15Z' and @SystemTime<='2023-06-14T13:54:15Z']]]
>
>
> » en type «System.Xml.XmlDocument». Erreur: «Le caractère '=', valeur hexadécimale 0x3D, ne peut pas commencer un nom.
> Ligne 6, position 90.» Au caractère C:\Program
> Files\NSClient++\scripts\OPSSI\test.ps1:31 : 63
>
> - ... = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $remoteServer -FilterXml $filter -Creden ...
> - ```
>                                                         ~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-WinEvent], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Can someone tell me how to correct the filter variable ?

I tried to execute this code to get a count of all the 5810 netlogon events on a remote server in the last half hour and I got the above error.

Comment: get-winevent -filterhashtable would probably be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `>=` and `<=` operators inside the XPath so they aren't interpreted as XML tag delimiters.

The escape sequence for `<` is `&lt;`, and for `>` it's `&gt;`:

```
$filter = @"
<QueryList>
    <Query>
        <Select Path="Security">
            *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=$eventID)]]
            and
            *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='$($startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))' and @SystemTime&lt;='$($endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))']]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
"@
```